# How many more "gimmicks" does adventure mode have?

Tags: plants-vs-zombies

I just started my second play through of adventure mode in Plants vs. Zombies, and now Crazy Dave is picking 3 (usually irrelevant) plants for me to use on each level.

After I finish this playthrough, will there be a new gimmick or handicap on further playthroughs?  How many different gimmicks are there on continued playthroughs, and on which playthroughs do each occur?

Comment: If you do not like the three items Crazy Dave has picked for you, you can quit the game before starting the level and restart it. Crazy Dave will pick three new items for you. At least I have observed this in the iPad version.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> After I finish this playthrough, will there be a new gimmick or handicap on further playthroughs?

No, the pick 3 is the only 'gimmick' for the adventure mode.  However, a new type of zombie will also show up on the 2nd play through, so keep an eye out.

Comment: Does the pick 3 occur on every subsequent playthrough as well?

Comment: yes, 12 chars..